# Как добавить валидацию contact form 7?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, как сделать проверку полей и если данные корректны, то сделать чтобы поле выделялось зеленым, а если нет, то красным и появлялось надпись ошибка под полем?

Comment: Красным по дефолту выделяется. Кроме того про это всё есть в документации к CF7 на оф сайте

Comment: https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/